# How to delete all the files under my app's NSDocumentsDirectory?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdocumentdirectory

I tried using

```
NSString *DocumentsDirectoryPath = //Code to fetch the Documents Directory Path;
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager removeItemAtPath:DocumentsDirectoryPath error:&error];
```

The above code deletes the whole Documents directory of my app, but I just want to delete **contents** of the Documents directory **not** the Documents directory itself.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
 NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];

 NSString *file;
 NSError *error;
 while ((file = [dirEnum nextObject])) 
 {
     NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir,file];
     // process the document
     [localFileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:&error ];
 }
 [localFileManager release];
```

Refer to this link for the answer:

[How to delete the contents of the Documents directory (and not the Documents directory itself)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749269/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-the-documents-directory-and-not-the-documents-dire)

Hope this helps all those who are looking out for a solution to this :)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but it's NSError *error not NSString *error

Comment: @Mike: This does not delete the contents of the documents directory.

Comment: Try it now - I added the missing line that creates the full path.

Comment: Note to self: wake up first, THEN answer questions.

Comment: @Rayfleck: I am having a warning at the this code block **while (file = [dirEnum nextObject])**

Comment: using iOS 4.3, to avoid this you need to change this block to `while ((file = [dirEnum nextObject]))`

Comment: I added the () to the code sample above.  Thanks to all of you for keeping me honest.

Comment: I think it's better to use [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]; rather than stringWithFormat