# NSHomeDirectory Remove All Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I remove all of the photos that I've saved in `NSHomeDirectory`? They are photos, saved in a path formatted as follows" `/var/mobile/Applications/3EEDBD68-5496-458D-9EF0-062746847C83/Photos/1234.png`.

And what do I call if I only want to remove a certain photo (i.e. that 1234.png listed above)?

Comment: First have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499903/how-to-delete-all-the-files-under-my-apps-nsdocumentsdirectory/5499941#5499941     You can iterate through all the files, and when the name matches, delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove one item, you could call:

```
NSString *filePath = @"/var/mobile/Applications/3EEDBD68-5496-458D-9EF0-062746847C83/Photos/1234.png";
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

To remove all of them:

```
NSString *directoryPath = @"/var/mobile/Applications/3EEDBD68-5496-458D-9EF0-062746847C83/Photos/";
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:directoryPath error:&error];
// Re-create the directory
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

See [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).