# How to clear the data of iOS app on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to clear the data of an app on iPhone/iPad without deleting the app? In Settings, general->usage->app where I can delete the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever data app downloads it goes to document directory only, so you can delete whichever data you want to delete from there. Here is the reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749269/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-the-documents-directory-and-not-the-documents-dir

Answer (score 1):

So these are the steps for clearing data

1) clear core Data model
[Delete/Reset all entries in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data)

2) Set all NSUserDefaults to their default value

3) Delete all files in document directory

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(cacheURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)
while let file = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(cacheURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)
}
```